# alternative to generate basic scaffolding in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I followed an online tutorial to learn the basics of MVC, which is [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller) btw, though I have a problem.
I use an Entity Framework add-on and it should generate the necessary CRUD views by itself, though when I make a controller to manage these views, it says:

MVC scaffolding does not support Entity Framework 6 or later. For more information please visit 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276833.

Does anybody know how to revert Entity Framework 6 to 5, so i can still generate these views? I'd rather not make them manually if I can avoid it.
Or is there another alternative to generating these Views?

Comment: Any chance you can upgrade your version of MVC?

Comment: I think you can use NuGet for uninstall EntityFramework by Package Manager Console and install previous version by this.

Comment: If possible, i'd rather stay with MVC 4. I need to know some of this for a college assignment and I'm not sure if upgrading to 5 is an option. Also How would I install a previous version? I can't seem to do so, except for deleting an old version and installing the newest once again

Comment: Use the nuget console, you can install any version you like.

Comment: You can't downgrade with nuget, so you'll have to uninstall 6, then install 5 and maybe do some of [these steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/upgradeEF6) in reverse.